# Why isn't my nested map function returning the updated data?

Tags: javascript, rxjs6

Can you help me with this one? My nested map :

```
        jobData.map(entity => {
                entity.entityType.dataProperties.map(property => {
                  if (/date/i.test(property.name)) {
                    if (entity[property.name] !== null) {
                      const formattedDate = moment(entity[property.name]).format('L');
 // Even this does not work:  const formattedDate = moment('01/01/2009).format('L');
                      return formattedDate;
                    }
                    return property;
                  }
                });
              });
      const newdata = jobData;
```

Is not returning the updated values.

I think I am misplacing my return statements.

Can someone help me out with this?

Comment: `const newdata = jobData;` won't have the result of any map ... and your outer map has no return statement, so the result of `jobData.map(entity => { ...})` will be an array of `undefined`

Comment: Add `return` before `entity.entityType.dataProperties .... `

Comment: Also missing return for `else` condition in inner map.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I realized I messed up in a few areas. I am not returning the entity and I was not updating the property with the new formatted date. Here is the working version.

```
 jobData.map(entity => {
        entity.entityType.dataProperties.map(property => {
          if (/date/i.test(property.name)) {
            if (entity[property.name] !== null) {
              const formattedDate = moment(entity[property.name]).format('L');
              entity[property.name] = formattedDate;
            }
            return property;
          }
        });
        return entity;
      });
```

Thanks to everyone who responded.